# SharePoint Online - Shredded Storage

Tags: sharepoint-online, versioning, shredded-storage

From this link:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sharepoint-online-service-description.aspx

SharePoint Online is supposed to support Shredded Storage and, if I'm understanding it correctly, then this is supposed to store only deltas in document versions.

I tested a fairly large document (~10MB) and it looks like full versions are being stored and not just deltas. I am looking at the site collection size (admin portal), document library/document size in Site Settings>Storage Metrics and Version History and they all add up to full versions and not deltas.

Can anyone confirm or verify if only deltas should be saved?

Comment: What is the document type in question in this scenario? I thought only office type documents benefited from shredded storage, but things like PDF  and images do not (which I've unscientifically verified).

Comment: I was tested with a Word document (.docx).

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to find it, but here is a link to the support article:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3038333

Basically, the SharePoint quota system doesn't talk directly to SQL to get the actual physical size of the shredded document, it uses the stored document size to 'estimate' the storage used to be counted against the overall quota.

it is possible the document is not shredded on the back end.  Depending on the settings, if your document is smaller than the shred size set by Microsoft it would not be shredded.

And last note - File types other than Office can be shredded.  Again, it's been a while since I've dug into it, but I recall the results were a bit inconsistent as to when non-office files were shredded.

Comment: This is correct. The savings for shredding only apply if you are OnPrem and pay for the SQL storage.  Office shredding works best since its processed a bit differently. All files are shredded (Some might only have 1 Shred, but it is counting as shredded)